# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrades breaks keyboard/mouse

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

I was using 19. Ubuntu recommended an update. I clicked all the buttons and let it do its thing.

After the update restarted the computer, I tried using the mouse. Nothing. I tried the keyboard. Nothing.

A couple manual restarts later, I get the mouse to work for half a second before it goes dead. I have no idea how to fix this type of problem. I suppose I could try a fresh install in the BIOS, but is there a possibly less extreme method? I spent a lot of time setting my environment up and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: Note: normally I would ssh into the machine, but that's not currently active after the restart.

Comment: live cd & chroot?

Comment: Had the same problem. Managed to get them both working bt spamming Ctrl+Alt+F3 while booting, and after getting to a black screen using once Ctrl+Alt+F1. I have no idea what I have done, and it doesn't actually solve the problem (rebooting the computer the problem persisted, and using the trick again solved it again). If anyone knows what I have done, please tell me XD

Comment: ok, after doing that and then disabling auto-login I think I solve the problem for now. This is sort of a solution, but I have no idea why it works or if it damages other stuff...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The auto-login has caused me problems before.

Comment: Update: I booted from a new install and overwrote my previous install. I lost my state, but not my data. The bios was still able to process keyboard, so I used it before log in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After upgrade to 20.04, mouse and keyboard are not recognised by the GUI. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> reboots the machine immediately without going through the normal shutdown questionnaire ("are you sure you want to restart?" thing). I have discovered that if I boot into recovery mode and then opt to continue to a normal boot, it all works as expected.

Booting straight into the GUI, however, does not work.

Comment: Same here. Everything worked fine in 19.04, but the upgrade to 20.04 breaks the mouse and keyboard. Has anyone figured this out? One suggestion that I found that seemed to work is to change from Gnome to a different window manager like KDE or LXDE. I tried that and it seemed to work, but there were other issues. A clean install of 20.04 brought the original problem back. SERIOUSLY thinking of ditching Ubuntu in favour of Manjaro or something

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, but with a fresh install. Everything was fine until I installed the nvidia proprietary driver. Then, no keyboard nor mouse anymore.

I found a trick that resolve my issue. I added "GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text" to /etc/default/grub, ran `sudo update-grub2` and then rebooted. gnome-session-flashback, autologin with nvidia driver and no issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - for me it had to do with auto-login and GDM.

I had to ssh in with X11 forwarding, launch the gnome-settings app and disable auto-login.

Then I went and apt removed with purge gdm and then re-installed it as well as the Ubuntu default login manager (forgot that it is called). It asked which login manager I wanted to use and I chose one.

I rebooted and it worked.

Sorry i don't have all the specific details here, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here on a zbook, after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 neither mouse nor keyboard were working anymore.
I could solve the mouse problem. I had to:

- Install `cygwin`, `xserver-org`, `xinit` and `ssh` on my windows machine
- In a cygwin terminal, start the X server: `startxwin`
- Then `ssh -Y` into the Ubuntu Linux machine
- To be able to start the GNome settings app I had to run `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/` first.
- Then started the `gnome-control-center`.
- There auto-login was off for my user. I wanted to turn it on, but the app said that it could not unlock these settings.
- So I had to edit the policy file: `sudo vi /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts.policy`
- There I set `allow_any` to yes.
- Then I restarted the `gnome-control-center` and activated auto-login for my user.
- Finally: `reboot`

Now it auto-logs-in to my user account, the mouse is working, but the keyboard is still not working. Hopefully I find a solution for that too.
Maybe the detailed list of steps helps somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

**Laptop keyboard and touchpad fail caused by "tablet-mode".**

Notebook, laptop, linux misconfigured in distro Ubuntu and Fedora and
others for "tablet-mode".

**LUKS** can not be decrypted due to failing
keyboard.

Work around for Laptop Fujitsu Lifebook under linux are possible.

The issue about Keyboard and/or Touchpad not working is caused by "**tablet-mode**".
To analyze events triggering "tablet-mode" see here, please:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20

I experience issues with several different Laptops Fujitsu Lifebook E Series (Fujitsu LIFEBOOK E4511, E5510, ...) Same issues with Dell, Sony, Lenovo, ...

I never managed to eliminate tablet mode completely.

I experience the same issue with Ubuntu and Fedora (recent versions).

I worked around the issue successfully. All Laptops I dealt with have circumvented  these (two different) issues.

Try solutions bit by bit, never as a watering can. Analyze.

All information retrieved from other sources, thanks a lot to the people willing to share solutions and hints.

In rare cases problem arises even when using USB-thumb-stick (this normally works fine - proof it is no systemic / unresolvable issue).

### keyboard

Missing keyboard is related to an early kernel module. Reason: The error occurs during boot process (long before X Window initialization): LUKS pwd can not be keyed in. Even function keys are "disconnected".

### touchpad

A touchpad not working has other reasons.

It seems to be the case, there are

- missing kernel modules or
- modules blocking functionality because they are active.

quick workaround for instant help:
If it is possible to reach X Window mode it often helps to close the lid and(!) wait until some sleep mode steped in. Waking up the laptop almost always activates keyboard and most times the touchpad.

### remediation or work around

One or a combination of these steps helped me to work around the issue:

- load hid modules
- block intel module
- block elan module
- install recent kernel
- grub process modules differently

Of course there are more ways to resolve it. Please document them in "comments" or your own contribution, please.

### **block intel module**

In

> /etc/modprobe.d/

create a new file:

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf

with the following two lines in it:

```
# bug  in module breaks keyboard, so do not load it (askubuntu.com 127820)
blacklist intel_vbtn
```

### **block elan module**

The elan_i2c module can block the keyboard in some cases of "tablet mode".
Block elan_i2c module in grub. Change

> /etc/default/grub

and set
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c"`

(back up and eliminate all previous stuff between quotes)
and check for deviations in spelling of the module!

### **load hid modules**

This frequently helps with the touchpad.
For spontaneous remediation after successful boot invoke terminal and execute

```
sudo modprobe i2c-hid
sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi
```

To make your solution persistent amend or create file

> /etc/modules

## /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.

Just add the two lines

```
i2c-hid
i2c-hid-acpi
```

More recent installations use location

> /etc/modules-load.d/

This helped with many touch pads like the „DesignWare“ Touchpad in a Lifebook E5511.
It is possible to use grub for this means:
`GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="i2c_hid"` (but failed for me)

### **grub process modules differently**

at least one case of "tablet mode" keyboard failure was avoided by reconfiguring modules in boot process using grub.
In grub (

> /etc/default/grub

) change line as

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

This may need combination with recent kernel installation.

### **install recent kernel**

in one case it helped to install a recent kernel.

Just take the latest stable one. This should do the job. Configure grub to support fallback mode etc.!
used source:

> https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/

FF!

PS: In grub always use

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=false
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=false
```

to support analysis.

All information retrieved from other sources, thanks a lot to the people willing to share solutions and contribute help.

Answer (score -1):

half of my keyboard was not working. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688445/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working). But the settings on my laptop were fine. Anyway I did the wrong settings.
**Enabled: Settings>Universal Access>Typing>Typing Assist(Access X)**
I enabled all the settings in that dialogue box.

closed the settings. The keyboard stopped working altogether.

Disabled: Settings>Universal Access>Typing>Typing Assist(Access X)

Now the keyboard is working :D

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to the question. The user's _mouse_ isn't working.

Comment: Unrelated since there is no mouse or keyboard